# How can I convert list into string, and later back to list type?

Tags: python

How can I convert list into string, and later back to list type?

```
ids = [64L, 65L]
ids_string = str(ids) # I need save this in `models.CharField`

print list(ids_string) # not working -> ['[', '6', '4', 'L', ',', ' ', '6', '5', 'L', ']']
```

Comment: You'll probably need a parser for Python lists syntax

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @laike9m `ids = [64L, 65L]`

Comment: Briefly: use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `list()`.